# Missing special characters and tags while parsing HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a HTML document using `BeautifulSoup` with Python.

But it stops parsing at special characters, like here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = '''
<html>
    <body>
        <div>And I said «What the %&#@???»</div>
        <div>some other text</div>
    </body>
</html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc,  'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

This code should output the whole document. Instead, it prints only

```
<html>
<body>
<div>And I said «What the %</div></body></html>
```

**The rest of the document is apparently lost**. It was stopped by the combination `'&#'`.

The question is, how to either setup BS or preprocess the document, to avoid such problems but lose as little text (which may be informative) as possible?

I use bs4 of version 4.6.0 with Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10.

**Update**. The method `soup.prettify()` does not work, because the `soup` is already broken.

Comment: `&` is used for HTML entities - like `&gt;` for `>` or `&lt;` for `<`. You can try to `doc.replace("&", "other char")` but this way you can loose correct entities like  `&gt;`, `&lt;`, `&nbsp;` etc.

Comment: I know it. The question is, how to clear it from the text, while keeping the HTML entities intact.

Comment: if you know that there is `%&#@???` or `%&` or `&#` then you can replace exactly this string. If you don't know if there are other similar strings then it can be problem. Maybe with some regex you could catch all strings which have `&` but don't have ending `;`

Comment: I don't know it for advance - I am trying to parse a million documents, and this error was in the 5000'th :)
Well, I'll try to look for such a regex.

Comment: as I see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) correct entity is `&chars;` or `&#digits;` so if you have something different then it can't be entity - it could be easy to create regex like `&(#[^0-9]|[^a-zA-Z])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the "html5lib" as the parser instead of "html.parser" in your `BeautifulSoup` object. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = '''
<html>
    <body>
        <div>And I said «What the %&#@???»</div>
        <div>some other text</div>
    </body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc,  'html5lib')
#          different parser  ^
```

Now, if you'll print `soup` it will display your desired string:

```
>>> print(soup)
<html><head></head><body>
        <div>And I said «What the %&amp;#@???»</div>
        <div>some other text</div>

</body></html>
```

From the [Difference Between Parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) document:

> Unlike `html5lib`, `html.parser` makes no attempt to create a well-formed HTML document by adding a  tag. Unlike lxml, it doesn’t even bother to add an  tag.

Comment: @DavidDale : Sorry, my bad. Was confused with something else. Updated the answer